# How to add a number to a jQuery Object itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a number to a particular jQuery Object like this.

```
$('#count').text(Number($('#count').text()) + 1);
```

It works, but it's a little redundant to write same selector and `text()` method twice.
Is there better way to do this with jQuery, like `$('#count').text(Number(this) + 1);`?

Comment: how about $('#count').text(Number($(this)) + 1);

Comment: there is - don't use the document as your primary data storage.

Comment: @C-link This doesn't work neither.

Comment: @C-link In this context `this` will be a Window.

Comment: @c-link that probably won't work. And if it does, you can replace both occurences of the selection

Comment: @JanDvorak No, I don't. I just update UI by using ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with the callback argument to [`$.fn.text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text):

```
$('#count').text(function(i, oldText) {
    return +oldText + 1;
});
```

Within the callback, `oldText` is set to the existing value. We use the unary plus `+` operator to convert it to a number (this is better than using `Number()`). The return value of the callback is set as the element's new text value.